# too many function calls

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I wrote the following code parsing a `csv` file:

```
var result = FullFile.Split('\n')
  .Select(s => new 
  { FirstName = s.Split(',')[(int)FirstName.Value],
  SirName = s.Split(',')[(int)sirName.Value],
  garde = s.Split(',')[(int)Grade.Value] });
```

Now, I use the function `Split` too many times with the same arguments, and on the same object.

Is there a way to carry on using the lambada expression, and cut down this function calls?

*Any other comments on my coding are welcome*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can split once in the first `Select`, and pass the result down the chain to the second `Select`, like this:

```
var result = FullFile
    .Split('\n')
    .Select(line => line.Split(','))
    .Select(tt => new 
        { FirstName = tt[(int)FirstName.Value],
          SirName = tt[(int)sirName.Value],
          garde = tt[(int)Grade.Value] });
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var result = from var s in FullFile.Split('\n')
                  let x = s.Split(',')
                  select new {
                                FirstName = x[(int)FirstName.Value],
                                SirName = x[(int) SirName.Value],
                                Grade = x[(int) Grade.Value]
                             };
```

Comment: FYI, you may have meant "SurName", not "SirName".